# Error when converting working CosmosDB Query to C# code

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple CosmosDB query that works as follows

```
SELECT c.variantId
FROM c IN jongel.BasicData.base.sales.variants
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.globalTradeItemNumber.globalTradeItemNumberType, {"GTIN":"05662570363012"}, true)
```

returning the expected value.

Then I put this into my C# code as follows

```
FeedIterator setIterator = itemContainer.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(
               $"SELECT c.variantId " +
               $"FROM c IN jongel.BasicData.base.sales.variants " +
               $"WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.globalTradeItemNumber.globalTradeItemNumberType, {{\"GTIN\":\"{barCode}\"}}, true)",
               requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
               {
                   PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("XXX"),
                   MaxConcurrency = 1,
                   MaxItemCount = 1
               });
```

But this returns no result so I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the escaping in the string of the {} and " but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

How can I convert the query correctly?

Comment: According to [MSDN][1] you can use double braces to escape.  You should be able to confirm if the query text is correct by first assigning it to a variable.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#how-do-i-include-literal-braces--and--in-the-result-string

Comment: @Kami I checked and the strings are identical to my working query, I am lost now I was sure that was the issue

Comment: If there is no issue with how the query itself is created, then maybe check that the data is present in the database, ie, that the query should work and return the expected data.  If that is correct as well, then ensure you are connecting to the expected database.

Comment: Done that running the query in azure exporer works fine so I know the data is there and I know I am in the right DB, need take a break and look again in 2 hours I must be missing something to easy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by using single quotations instead of double quotations. Below is one of my methods in the repository class which works perfectly.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Fixture>> GetUnorderedSeasonFixtures(PartitionKey partitionKey)
        {
            FeedIterator feedIterator = this.Container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(
                $"select * from c where c.streamId = '{partitionKey.ToString()}'",
                null, new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = partitionKey});
```

...